# Divide a python list into Nested List

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

Hello python enthusiasts !! 
I have a text file with content like this.

```
Pakistan[country]\n
Karachi\n
lahore\n
islamabad\n
UAE[country]\n
dubai\n
sharjah\n
India[country]\n
goa\n
chennai\n
```

I read this file using this code.

```
mylist = list(open('data.txt', 'r'))
```

now i have all of elements in list structure, but i want to transform this into a nested list, a list structure like below.

```
[['Pakistan', 'Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'],['UAE', 'dubai', 'sharjah'],['India', 'goa', 'chennai']]
```

Kindly help me to transform this text into above structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* this solution is not for the faint-hearted, and does not really prioritize readability.

I'm a little intrigued that none of the currently posted answers solves this issue by `.split("[country]")`. Here is a solution by list comprehensions:

```
 # read file this way to preserve line structure:
 with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read().strip().split("\n")

 # First: move the "[country]" tag from behind to in front of the name.
 # Also, I replace "[country]" with "*" for no other reason than that it's shorter
 data = ",".join(["*"+x.replace("[country]","") if x.endswith("[country]") else x for x in data])

 # Then, split on "[country]", that is: ",*",
 # But keep in mind that the very first country will have prefix "*", not ",*"
 data = [x.replace("*","").split(",") for x in data.split(",*")]

 print(data)
 #[['Pakistan', 'Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'], ['UAE', 'dubai', 'sharjah'], ['India', 'goa', 'chennai']]
```

Another, much cleaner approach if you're able to change the format of your data file such that the tag `[country]` is set in front of the country name instead of after, then it is a little simpler, and you'll get away with a simple one-liner:

```
 with open('data2.txt', 'r') as f:
     data = f.read().strip().split("[country]")

 data = [x.strip().replace("[country]","").split("\n") for x in data[1:]]

 print(data)
 #[['Pakistan', 'Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'], ['UAE', 'dubai', 'sharjah'], ['India', 'goa', 'chennai']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for entry in mylist:
        if entry.endswith('[country]'):
            country= entry[:entry.rindex('[')]
            result.append([country])
        else:
            result[-1].append(entry)


>>> result
[['Pakistan', 'Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'], ['UAE', 'dubai', 'sharjah'], ['India', 'goa', 'chennai']]
```

Comment: I suggest using `country.replace("[country]","")` instead of the slicing: more explicit and understandable,

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```py
results = []
tmp =[]
with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "country" in line:
            if tmp:
                results.append(tmp)
             tmp = []
             line = line.replace("[country]", "")
        tmp.append(line.strip())
     results.append(tmp)
print(results)
```

Comment: Doesn't add the last country to results. Also, is ```if tmp:``` check needed?

Comment: @MePsyDuck corrected thanks, yes, because if the first lines don't start with country.

Answer (score 1):

```py
mylist = list(open('data.txt', 'r'))

superlist = []
countrylist = []
for entry in mylist:
    if '[country]' in entry:
        superlist.append(countrylist)
        countrylist = [entry.replace('[country]', '')]
    else:
        countrylist.append(entry)

if len(countrylist) > 0:
    superlist.append(countrylist)
```

Comment: You don't close the file, bad idea. Your `if len` is outside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = StringIO("""  
Pakistan[country]\n
Karachi\n
lahore\n
islamabad\n
UAE[country]\n
dubai\n
sharjah\n
India[country]\n
goa\n
chennai\n
""")


df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep='\s+', engine='python',header=None)
```

---

using `re.split`

```
country_l = ' '.join(list(df[0]))
[i.replace('[country]','').split() for i in re.split('\s(?=\w*\[country\])',country_l)]

##output
[['Pakistan', 'Karachi', 'lahore', 'islamabad'],
 ['UAE', 'dubai', 'sharjah'],
 ['India', 'goa', 'chennai']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = list(open('data.txt', 'r'))    
j = -1
for country in my_list:
    if country.__contains__('[country]'):
        country = country[:country.find('[country]')]
        result.append([country])
        j += 1
    else:
        country = country[:country.find('\n')]
        result[j].append(country)
```